# Chart.JS not showing last zero in a decimal

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the chartjs line chart and on the tooltip where it shows the number I would have 102.50.

However the chart shows 102.5.

The only code I have that manipulates the tooltip is

```
tooltips: {
        callbacks: {
            label: function(tooltipItems, data) {
                return "Total:  $" + tooltipItems.yLabel.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
                }
            }
           },
```

I've tried without my tooltip option and it still cuts off that final zero.  I do know that the number being provided is 102.50

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing `tooltipItems.yLabel.toFixed(2);` and build upon from this solution :)